# How can I use filters with Algolia's InstantSearch?

Tags: android, kotlin, algolia

I'm using instant search on Android and I'm trying to filter my index by one Id and the name of the object.

The thing is I'm using the InstantSearch object and the searcher. If adding the filter(ID) to the query, the response is always blank.

Here is my code:

```
private val searcher = Searcher.create(APP_ID, API_KEY, INDEX_OBJECT)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)

        setSupportActionBar(tbSearch)
        supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_normal_48px)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
        val q = Query()
        q.filters = "id:Hj5RFIzLjk5XTJOdODeu"
        searcher.query = q
        val helper = InstantSearch(this, searcher)
        helper.search()
    }
```

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? If no, don't forget to accept an answer or update your question appropriately :)

Comment: Actually the answer worked, but when I'm searching using the search box in algolia's sdk. The search is performed in the entire index instead in the part filtered by the id

Comment: Do you see the same thing when applying the same filter in the [algolia Dashboard](https://algolia.com/explorer)?

Answer (score 0):

Your Query object is initialized with an empty constructor.

See this line in your code.

```
val q = Query()
```

Add query string like this.

```
val q = Query("Your Query String")
```

See here for more info: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android#search

Comment: This is not required to use filters.

Answer (score 0):

You are using InstantSearch Android correctly, this is the expected way to pass a filter with an empty query.

Have you tried the same query in your dashboard to see if it brings the same result? You might have forgotten to [enable faceting](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesForFaceting/) on this `id` attribute.